# Error in GNU Prolog

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I have this code :

```
:- public       
    queens / 1.

:- mode
    forbidden(+, +, +, +),
    least_room_to_move(+, -, -, -),
    lr2m(+, +, +, -, -, -),
    make_initial_table(+, -),
    make_initial_table(+, +, -),
    number_list(+, -),
    place(+, -),
    prune(+, +, +, -),
    prune(+, +, +, +, -),
    shorter(+, +).
```

And I get these errors :

> e.pl:1:2: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
>   e.pl:5:2: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Could that be [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/) code ?

The first directive should be about exporting a procedure, remaining are requested by 
compiler to provide efficient code.

GNU Prolog doesn't have modules, and provides a fairly good compilation by default.

Try removing directives altogether.